# Load jquery only for certain pages in the backend

Tags: functions, jquery

I have a set of custom theme settings in my functions.php file.

**In order to arrange some things I want to load jquery ONLY to my functions.php file.**

What I read in wordpress is this:

If it was needed within the admin, you could use the admin_enqueue_scripts action instead, **however this enqueues it on ALL admin pages, which often leads to plugin/core conflicts**, ultimately breaking the WordPress admin experience. Instead, You should only load it on the individual pages you need it, See the Load scripts only on Plugin pages section for an example of that.

This is the wordpress recommended script for enabling jquery only on plugin pages.

**Can I adapt this script to enable my script just for the theme options page?**

```
<?php
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_plugin_admin_init' );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_admin_menu' );

    function my_plugin_admin_init() {
        /* Register our script. */
        wp_register_script( 'my-plugin-script', plugins_url('/script.js', __FILE__) );
    }

    function my_plugin_admin_menu() {
        /* Register our plugin page */
        $page = add_submenu_page( 'edit.php', // The parent page of this menu
                                  __( 'My Plugin', 'myPlugin' ), // The Menu Title
                                  __( 'My Plugin', 'myPlugin' ), // The Page title
                  'manage_options', // The capability required for access to this item
                  'my_plugin-options', // the slug to use for the page in the URL
                                  'my_plugin_manage_menu' // The function to call to render the page
                               );

        /* Using registered $page handle to hook script load */
        add_action('admin_print_styles-' . $page, 'my_plugin_admin_styles');
    }

    function my_plugin_admin_styles() {
        /*
         * It will be called only on your plugin admin page, enqueue our script here
         */
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin-script' );
    }

    function my_plugin_manage_menu() {
        /* Output our admin page */
    }
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, functions.php is not a template file, do you mean only load the script on the frontend, and not the backend?

Comment: ah nevermind I've edited your questions title to make more sense

Comment: Yes, it makes much more sense... functions.php is a page from my backend located in my theme folder. I need to load jquery to it in order to do some styling

Comment: jQuery is already loaded on all of the WordPress backend pages, you don't need to load it again.

Comment: in functions.php without loading jquery the script does not work

Comment: In that case, it's likely that you're not loading your script with a dependency on jQuery. Please post the full code you're trying to use so we can attempt to recreate your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_options_page` returns the same value as `add_submenu_page` and can be used in exactly the same way as the code you posted.

This will load your scripts only on that page.

You can also request the global `$pagenow` variable if you'd rather do it that way.